# Tree-shaking vs selective import in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, tree-shaking

In Dart, we have the ability to selectively import parts of files or libraries with the *show* keyword...

```dart
    import 'package:http/http.dart' show get;
```

...but Flutter makes tree-shaking.
Has the *show* keyword any benefit in Flutter or is it completely meanless?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

import/exports directives have nothing to do with tree-shaking.

`show`/`hide`/`as` are instead used to not pollute the auto-complete, keep some classes "private", or resolve conflicts.

Say you're using both RxDart and Mobx: both packages define an `Observable` class.

If you tried to import both `package:rxdart/rxdart.dart;` and `package:mobx/mobx.dart` in the same file, then you would have a conflict.

You would, therefore, need to use `show`/`hide`/`as` to tell the compiler what's the solution.

It could be:

- "I don't care about Mobx's Observable":

```dart
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
import 'package:mobx/mobx.dart' hide Observable;
```

- "I want only Mobx's "reaction":

```dart
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
import 'package:mobx/mobx.dart' show reaction;
```

- "I'll use an alias because I may use both"

```dart
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart' as rxdart;
import 'package:mobx/mobx.dart' as mobx;
```

Comment: But let's say I have a simple issue, I need to know if my platform is IOS. I import `dart:io` to use `Platform.isIOS` but nothing else from the package. Will tree-shaking make the final app the same size as if I would have done `import 'dart:io' show Platform`?

Comment: Yes. As I said in the answer, tree-shaking works withot having to use `show` & co